# How do you get node using npm request module to work that currently works in Postman?

Tags: node.js, postman

First there have been many questions similar to this one but none of them have solved my problem.

Windows 10 x64
Node 12.6.0
request 2.88.0
Postman 7.2.2

Postman has a feature to generate code for npm request.

Postman works fine and returns data.  In code the post works and the body returns the api info but with no data.

Here is the code I am using

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://www.netflix.com/api/shakti/v73fa49e3/pathEvaluator',
    qs:
        { drmSystem: 'widevine',
            isWatchlistEnabled: 'false',
            isVolatileBillboardsEnabled: 'true',
            falcor_server: '0.1.0',
            withSize: 'true',
            materialize: 'true' },
    headers:
        { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            'Content-Length': '754',
            Host: 'www.netflix.com',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'X-Netflix.browserName': 'Chrome',
            'X-Netflix.osVersion': '10.0',
            'X-Netflix.playerThroughput': '58194',
            Referer: 'https://www.netflix.com/browse/my-list',
            Accept: '*/*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
            'X-Netflix.esnPrefix': 'NFCDCH-02-',
            'X-Netflix.uiVersion': 'v73fa49e3',
            'X-Netflix.browserVersion': '75',
            Connection: 'keep-alive',
            'X-Netflix.clientType': 'akira',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            DNT: '1',
            'X-Netflix.osFullName': 'Windows 10',
            Origin: 'https://www.netflix.com' },
    form:
        { path:
                [ '["mylist",["id","length","name","requestId","trackIds"]]',
                    '["mylist",{"from":0,"to":400},["availability","availabilityEndDateNear","delivery","interactiveBookmark","maturity","numSeasonsLabel","queue","releaseYear","runtime","seasonCount","summary","title","userRating","userRatingRequestId"]]',
                    '["mylist",{"from":0,"to":400},"current",["hasAudioDescription","summary"]]',
                    '["mylist",{"from":0,"to":400},"boxarts","_233x131","webp"]' ],

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: "Postman works fine and returns data. In code the post works and the body returns the api info but with no data.". - Hi dan! So then following this sentence that I quoted it's not clear what's the problem since you say POST works and body return the api info but with no data. But should data be there at all? Which status code for this request? It's no need to hove the response body if status code 204 for example. If you have the correct status code 200/204 and api response then the most likely there's nothing to do with npm or node at all.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me.  I have a post statement setup in postman that connects to the api.  When I run this data is returned      "jsonGraph": {
        "mylist": {
            "length": {
                "$type": "atom",
                "value": 362
            },
            "nam

I then exported this post from postman using postman's node request code generator.  When I run the exported code in node no data is returned.  Hope this clears things up.  Thanks

The status code is 200 and the body data is {"jsonGraph":{},"paths":[]}.  when I run it in postman

Comment: I just used Postman to generate the code in curl instead of node request and the correct data is returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you.

```
const request = require("request");

// URL 
const reqUrl = 'https://www.netflix.com/api/shakti/v73fa49e3/pathEvaluator';

// HEADERS 
const reqHeaders = {
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'Content-Length': '754',
  Host: 'www.netflix.com',
  'Postman-Token': '845e51a3-67cf-4d93-8518-997a7e22f4b7,edf531a3-056c-493e-86b4-3003504214ff',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  'X-Netflix.browserName': 'Chrome',
  'X-Netflix.osVersion': '10.0',
  'X-Netflix.playerThroughput': '58194',
  Referer: 'https://www.netflix.com/browse/my-list',
  Accept: '*/*',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
  'X-Netflix.esnPrefix': 'NFCDCH-02-',
  'X-Netflix.uiVersion': 'v73fa49e3',
  'X-Netflix.browserVersion': '75',
  Connection: 'keep-alive',
  Cookie: 'memclid=0abfdde3-fdf8-4e6e-acc5-dae57e09941d; clSharedContext=7461c7cc-5a56-4e5f-b733-6febb8acd74e; lhpuuidh-browse-JGKS7R3LLZAC5M5AEZ5UK2FYIQ=US%3AEN-US%3A5f656cb6-ec81-4ffe-84b1-63a759e1f49b_ROOT; lhpuuidh-browse-JGKS7R3LLZAC5M5AEZ5UK2FYIQ-T=1562281011685; lhpuuidh-browse-vvvvvrrerr=US%3AEN-US%3Abdfaa1e1-6464-4f31-bd4e-1c3e1c1d8a39_ROOT; lhpuuidh-browse-SN75QUHUXBHIAR23$TOJ3MZFVNQ7VYM-T=1562281110358; flwssn=8acee0b3-44c5-47ca-83ca-d6df6812aae6; profilesNewSession=0; NetflixId=v%3D2%26c$t3DBQAOAAEBEG4pPrNrBZszdxk8h2J8z1-BwG9mHUGvDRv7ORSv67vAlP-SdTbWM7Nx0lORLEed8a5yNR37Ws-WNM9SGe27SaTdJVqavU0oXha4WaZ0BWfDqu_6jQVvSXK0448K3QbpZ_QdubFfWu0h0SFXFxvXYR5cS-ks0bg7SF4V8iLC15QA-Lr7f354xZWDdAWV1xEYPVT06ptRRqi7g1cLE778U9WP9LCJYARWmuFPlxGVe4cmwxhQRGShu5IN6ucYcSe4OEJL-Ew1Yxd5mk4_0fhzkf05QAnirTzm5BpP7h07p06D3ZOdOzGsBlI-fV51g9eXvlA1kTL7irOJ6nq6NaXz1L397kEjcEvpgcCS5pslq3a9qEQ60KOathphl5GLZGxn4xvXIcx5Hm8cfs4iVng1kn9elzavpq9AbE8ce9pbbS82IF16MlOcVwICJXB9z_TNZ9ejkmMtACl8mKmJoXBZIRYZJXCbE0wcj-R4WQKZDqQJvWsPb_3a0PQBGoZojZ8pbdM3LUf21uxPBbFa8xmikLTMUM6FMbrMhpNqJ9tiQ5X2eAqtaeRHb3f7Dooz-E04hw9Or5_UaeX9264Rc6xtHpjDDfgg57LCza3BohNv3ag14Es.%26bt%3Ddbl%26ch%3DAQEAEAABABTq8jfw7-uqTNfPp2rJYz9aGgfupIDvmNU.%26mac%3DAQEAEAABABTp8m22vbAq4UFdbkSZ8fwNXxu5lA2rUaQ.; SecureNetflixId=v%3D2%26mac%3DAQEAEQABABRFqE_Sb9qJah1InM9FBWZTOIDUlQqiX8s.%26dt%3D1562307985579; nfvdid=BQFmAAEBEBhpAs5prG2e%2FuSxGlzoowlgHvZPo5LP%2F2%2BADgwBZrcGgdZwsfNb0vdVGKri8rGJwZ8gD9CRQs66NlMtqB3G%2FZYyTtnkl9qZoWp9AUfIhhmJPVbVTcsWX9j3ohgTuunD58WRtFBLFwu4HRlh2f70lszp; playerPerfMetrics=%7B%22uiValue%22%3A%7B%22throughput%22%3A59173%7D%2C%22mostRecentValue%22%3A%7B%22throughput%22%3A59173%7D%7D; cL=1562307988270%7C156230796458086017%7C156230796487562712%7C%7C8%7CTR7OX5P3Z5DY3DVRBZH7CZQVDI,memclid=0abfdde3-fdf8-4e6e-acc5-dae57e09941d; clSharedContext=7461c7cc-5a56-4e5f-b733-6febb8acd74e; lhpuuidh-browse-JGKS7R3LLZAC5M5AEZ5UK2FYIQ=US%3AEN-US%3A5f656cb6-ec81-4ffe-84b1-63a759e1f49b_ROOT; lhpuuidh-browse-JGKS7R3LLZAC5M5AEZ5UK2FYIQ-T=1562281011685; lhpuuidh-browse-SN75QUHUXBHITOJ3MZFVNQ7VYM=US%3AEN-US%3Abdfaa1e1-6464-4f31-bd4e-1c3e1c1d8a39_ROOT; lhpuuidh-browse-SN75QUHUXBHITOJ3MZFVNQ7VYM-T=1562281110358; flwssn=8acee0b3-44c5-47ca-83ca-d6df6812aae6; profilesNewSession=0; NetflixId=v%3D2%26ct%3DBQAOAAEBEG4pPrNrBZszdxk8h2J8z1-BwG9mHUGvDRv7ORSv67vAlP-SdTbWM7Nx0lORLEed8a5yNR37Ws-WNM9SGe27SaTdJVqavU0oXha4WaZ0BWfDqu_6jQVvSXK0448K3QbpZ_QdubFfWu0h0SFXFxvXYR5cS-ks0bg7SF4V8iLC15QA-Lr7f354xZWDdAWV1xEYPVT06ptRRqi7g1cLE778U9WP9LCJYARWmuFPlxGVe4cmwxhQRGShu5IN6ucYcSe4OEJL-Ew1Yxd5mk4_0fhzkf05QAnirTzm5BpP7h07p06D3ZOdOzGsBlI-fV51g9eXvlA1kTL7irOJ6nq6NaXz1L397kEjcEvpgcCS5pslq3a9qEQ60KOathphl5GLZGxn4xvXIcx5Hm8cfs4iVng1kn9elzavpq9AbE8ce9pbbS82IF16MlOcVwICJXB9z_TNZ9ejkmMtACl8mKmJoXBZIRYZJXCbE0wcj-R4WQKZDqQJvWsPb_3a0PQBGoZojZ8pbdM3LUf21uxPBbFa8xmikLTMUM6FMbrMhpNqJ9tiQ5X2eAqtaeRHb3f7Dooz-E04hw9Or5_UaeX9264Rc6xtHpjDDfgg57LCza3BohNv3ag14Es.%26bt%3Ddbl%26ch%3DAQEAEAABABTq8jfw7-uqTNfPp2rJYz9aGgfupIDvmNU.%26mac%3DAQEAEAABABTp8m22vbAq4UFdbkSZ8fwNXxu5lA2rUaQ.; SecureNetflixId=v%3D2%26mac%3DAQEAEQABABRFqE_Sb9qJah1InM9FBWZTOIDUlQqiX8s.%26dt%3D1562307985579; nfvdid=BQFmAAEBEBhpAs5prG2e%2FuSxGlzoowlgHvZPo5LP%2F2%2BADgwBZrcGgdZwsfNb0vdVGKri8rGJwZ8gD9CRQs66NlMtqB3G%2FZYyTtnkl9qZoWp9AUfIhhmJPVbVTcsWX9j3ohgTuunD58WRtFBLFwu4HRlh2f70lszp; playerPerfMetrics=%7B%22uiValue%22%3A%7B%22throughput%22%3A59173%7D%2C%22mostRecentValue%22%3A%7B%22throughput%22%3A59173%7D%7D; cL=1562307988270%7C156230796458086017%7C156230796487562712%7C%7C8%7CTR7OX5P3Z5DY3DVRBZH7CZQVDI; memclid=0abfdde3-fdf8-4e6e-acc5-dae57e09941d; SecureNetflixId=v%3D2%26mac%3DAQEAEQABABSBtymZf_WUUxqlLjxi9Tcz1N9HfVu27lk.%26dt%3D1562373989602; NetflixId=ct%3DBQAOAAEBENa9KbSSXAiVkZ-nyrCx-eqB4E5bZ_0MPQueZB7vgCnv5dv90cB7Lw9mzIa4SiUj09G9TjdSTfh56B6WIBR0QhsgE99T2rPoDs0iKPhegsCl20lLNc8LFYmhH1duOYA09lPXxaW7fjFea3v7KdbVhEkoCQKMJ5XM4G6vuMmMMUWGnqftt8Fa7xGmgxsrZBYxLhyqA_EC0YKIIlXeNC2kzcc7igTTU1LPIgQmvq-eOkskaCnkfX995ZzIj1yrcXa6xEIprO7E2buzF0nnDcqiiLwDwWNOF_DNCiyHxT9SbBTeaacoAHVI4iXnZ3HY4GVHJuq7gJEtGR8fwraPVyCIc5jeiFu1FXdKogro5w22TrQNNQU-eDBEBoLImmk1pZqBwbSYVrsk86JkqGtWmuxFGyyBTmTSyrfhcETUDOSPvveWCaiBA617rqOTP7n8UbfBnWDCoDS1FCweAGM1K_7JVOY3f7Bo6CVUvLODKutGsuXar9GiOmPoCJMiCO-MCnda3BS-oqROhm5nOEL5rCWRlxlIgn8vrQB5ELWADX3qwwSEi7yTZ-hHaQSI5xIkqFcgeH0LT27fpxdrz01jlZ2o1glDQhBKoO34WTmllvCDQzqcBL7_nNaE4Y9I30N00O18pBXIgHYloRDnOUUxV66_9AxBiw..%26bt%3Ddbl%26ch%3DAQEAEAABABTq8jfw7-uqTNfPp2rJYz9aGgfupIDvmNU.%26v%3D2%26mac%3DAQEAEAABABQmYnZZPVCzzqbysYph9oT_ddbBqaBhqLM.',
  'X-Netflix.osName': 'Windows',
  'x-netflix.request.client.user.guid': 'JGKS7R3LLZAC5M5AEZ5UK2FYIQ',
  'X-Netflix.clientType': 'akira',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  DNT: '1',
  'X-Netflix.osFullName': 'Windows 10',
  Origin: 'https://www.netflix.com'
};

// QUERY PARAMS
const queryParams = {
  drmSystem: 'widevine',
  isWatchlistEnabled: 'false',
  isVolatileBillboardsEnabled: 'true',
  falcor_server: '0.1.0',
  withSize: 'true',
  materialize: 'true',
};

// REQ BODY
const reqBody = {
  path:
    ['["mylist",["id","length","name","requestId","trackIds"]]',
      '["mylist",{"from":0,"to":400},["availability","availabilityEndDateNear","delivery","interactiveBookmark","maturity","numSeasonsLabel","queue","releaseYear","runtime","seasonCount","summary","title","userRating","userRatingRequestId"]]',
      '["mylist",{"from":0,"to":400},"current",["hasAudioDescription","summary"]]',
      '["mylist",{"from":0,"to":400},"boxarts","_233x131","webp"]'],
  authURL: '1562307985945.HbhvPp8+bh2fI7XfVLhH3Dj6zJc='
}

// OPTIONS
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: reqUrl,
  headers: reqHeaders,
  qs: queryParams,
  body: qs.stringify(reqBody),
  json: true,
};

request(options, (error, response, resBody) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  } else if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
    throw resBody;
  }
  return resBody;
});
```

Comment: added small fix to your answer -- body needs to be stringified  "body: qs.stringify(reqBody)",.  I will go ahead and award you the bounty.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem.  The api was expecting the data to be in the body query string stringified.

To do this remove the form variable from the request.  Then stringify the value of the form variable and send that as they body

Working code:

```
var request = require('request');
var qs = require('querystring')
var dataString = qs.stringify({
    path:
        ['["mylist",["id","length","name","requestId","trackIds"]]',
            '["mylist",{"from":0,"to":400},["availability","availabilityEndDateNear","delivery","interactiveBookmark","maturity","numSeasonsLabel","queue","releaseYear","runtime","seasonCount","summary","title","userRating","userRatingRequestId"]]',
            '["mylist",{"from":0,"to":400},"current",["hasAudioDescription","summary"]]',
            '["mylist",{"from":0,"to":400},"boxarts","_233x131","webp"]'],

})

var headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Origin': 'https://www.netflix.com',
    'Postman-Token': '9aceb650-3446-4d39-8234-b503138fd065',
    'Referer': 'https://www.netflix.com/browse/my-list',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Netflix.browserName': 'Chrome',
    'X-Netflix.browserVersion': '75',
    'X-Netflix.clientType': 'akira',
    'X-Netflix.esnPrefix': 'NFCDCH-02-',
    'X-Netflix.osFullName': 'Windows 10',
    'X-Netflix.osName': 'Windows',
    'X-Netflix.osVersion': '10.0',
    'X-Netflix.playerThroughput': '58194',
    'X-Netflix.uiVersion': 'v73fa49e3',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'Cookie': 'Cookie23werwetertert';

//var dataString = 'path=%5B%22mylist%22%2C%5B%22id%22%2C%22length%22%2C%22name%22%2C%22requestId%22%2C%22trackIds%22%5D%5D&path=%5B%22mylist%22%2C%7B%22from%22%3A0%2C%22to%22%3A400%7D%2C%5B%22availability%22%2C%22availabilityEndDateNear%22%2C%22delivery%22%2C%22interactiveBookmark%22%2C%22maturity%22%2C%22numSeasonsLabel%22%2C%22queue%22%2C%22releaseYear%22%2C%22runtime%22%2C%22seasonCount%22%2C%22summary%22%2C%22title%22%2C%22userRating%22%2C%22userRatingRequestId%22%5D%5D&path=%5B%22mylist%22%2C%7B%22from%22%3A0%2C%22to%22%3A400%7D%2C%22current%22%2C%5B%22hasAudioDescription%22%2C%22summary%22%5D%5D&path=%5B%22mylist%22%2C%7B%22from%22%3A0%2C%22to%22%3A400%7D%2C%22boxarts%22%2C%22_233x131%22%2C%22webp%22%5D&authURL=.%%3D';

var options = {
    json: true,
    url: 'https://www.netflix.com/api/shakti/v73fa49e3/pathEvaluator?drmSystem=widevine&isWatchlistEnabled=false&isVolatileBillboardsEnabled=true&falcor_server=0.1.0&withSize=true&materialize=true',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: dataString
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```